# Symfony 2/Propel: Class 'Phing' not found, autoloading?

Tags: php, symfony, propel, autoload, fatal-error

I've a weird problem with propel.
My configuration in `config.yml`:

```
propel:

    dbal:
        driver:     %database_driver%
        user:       %database_user%
        password:   %database_password%
        dsn:        %database_driver%:host=%database_host%;dbname=%database_name%;charset=UTF8
        path:       %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/propel
        phing_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/phing
```

I created my database with that command: `php app/console propel:database:create` and it worked very well but when I'm trying to create my first table with `php app/console propel:model:build` i've a fatal error telling: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phing' not found.`

I verified in the folder, everything is there. I guess that is an autoloading problem but I've followed the documentation at http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/symfony2/working-with-symfony2.html and http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/propel.html

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In which file and at which line is the error reported?

Answer (score 1):

Which dependencies management system do you use?

This is an autoloading issue, and you should add the following definition:

```
$loader->registerPrefixes(array(
    ...

    'Phing' => __DIR__.'/../path/to/phing/classes/phing',
));
```

where `path/to/phing` is the path where you installed **Phing**.

Comment: I use composer, and actually I forgot to add phing package. Since I added it, it works :) Or maybe it's because I changed the version of propel in the composer.json (checked in packagist).

Comment: Yes, you can add Phing in the composer file, or use the latest Propel version.